# Getting directory based the location of file C#

Tags: c#, directory, ncrunch

I'm trying to write a relative path from a file but the only relative paths I can get are from the running app file.

This is causing problems as NCrunch runs its test from a different directory so its failing all my tests because it cant find the files which are relative to my code file.

It's important that this be a relative path as there are several people working on this project so absolute paths don't work.

Is there any way to make the path relative to the .cs file where the code is written?

until now I've been using

```
 private static readonly string MyDocumentsRoot =      Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
        public static readonly string ApplicationRoot = MyDocumentsRoot + @"\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\";
```

but really need it to be a little more relative

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is well documented in NCRUNCH documentation:

[Implicit File Dependencies](http://www.ncrunch.net/documentation/considerations-and-constraints_implicit-file-dependencies)

The other solutions, sooner or later, will fail. (I had similar trouble with MSTest, which offers a similar solution).

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this code - based on `GetExecutingAssembly` method

```
string path  = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
string directory= Path.GetDirectoryName( path );
```

Or

```
  string path  = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetAssembly(YourClass).Location;
```

Comment: Thanks but GetExecutingAssembly doesn't allow arguments so this is just throwing a error

Comment: i updated post, GetAssembly take argument link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.reflection.assembly.getassembly.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use `str=Directory.getdirectory` which will give you the path of the app (the folders up until Release or Debug (where your app is located) and save it in a string (the method returns a string). After doing that you can use the `str.replace(str1,str2)` method which locates `str1` and replaces it with `str2`. Just don't forget that `\` inside a string is `\\` because `\` is an escape character. If you need help with escape characters let me know so I can help you with that as well.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](http://wiki.ncrunch.net/component-configuration.ashx) shows the paths are relative to the project file:

> For example, you could specify the following files to include:
>
> ```
> SpecialConfiguration\ImportantConfigFile.config
> ..\CustomBuild\**.*
> ..\..\TestResources\Spreadsheets\*.xls
> ```
>
> This would include an individual file (ImportantConfigFile.config), the entire contents of the `..\CustomBuild` directory, all of its subdirectories, and all .xls files within the `..\..\TestResources\Spreadsheets` directory.
>
> **All file paths must be specified relative to the project file's path on disk.** When NCrunch builds a workspace, it will automatically arrange all dependent files so they exist with the same relative paths in their workspace as they did in their original location.

Answer (score 0):

I usually place an old style ini-file where my executable resides. Here I store the absolute paths of files and folders required by the application. This also enables me to configure these pathes differently in a production enivronment (on the cutomers site) than on my development environment. Having just a copy of this ini-file in the folder from where NCrunch runs the assemlies would solve the problem.

My ini-file implementation searches all the folders, starting at the folder where the executable resides, towards the root folder, until it finds the ini-file. This enables me to have different executables using a common ini-file. E.g. if a place the ini-file in the `bin` folder both, the `Debug` and the `Release` version will automatically access the same ini-file.